# Yajur Veda and Puranas say that Earth is spherical. But Rig Veda 10.62.3 says that earth is "spread out"

Tags: rig-veda, yajur-veda, contradiction

Rig Veda 10.62.3:

> Ye raised the sun to heaven by everlasting law, and **spread the broad earth**, the mother out on every side  .
> Fair wealth of progeny by yours agnirases. Welcome the son of Manu, ye are the most wise.

Yet other scriptural texts say that the Earth is a sphere. How can this be reconciled?

Comment: Could not locate the word or phrase in sanskrit meaning spread out in RV 10.062.003

Comment: conflict in sanskrit interpretations are common when comparing english translations of sanskrit. It is most predominant in english translations on the internet and interpretations are that not literal.

Comment: As in uruchi somapitaye , there uru means spread out (over the Earth), the hint of sugandhim pushtivardhanam.

Answer (score 0):

Spherical earth means which we see from sky which contains 7 oceans 7 continents etc,
Flat earth means that we seeing everyday
Which is surrounded by oceans contains hills etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Rig Veda states the Earth is vast and spread out. Rather than referring to geometry it likely represents the bigness and vastness of the Earth. A primitive village person may think is the size of his country or even state. This verse hence helps visualize the expansiveness of the earth truly. I believe that verse talks about the 4 cardinal directions as well which proves my point.